# Problem in Building Spring Boot Batch Application: Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am building a Spring Boot application (version 2.7.7) to dump data from .csv to MySQL db. I am getting several exceptions on building the project.
**application.properties-**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch_db
spring.datasource.username=hbstudent
spring.datasource.password=hbstudent
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
server.port=8081

spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always 
#to initalize the tables
```

**Batch Configuration-**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing 
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> reader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<User> reader=new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("records.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper()); //how to map the line which is read.
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1); // skip lines when error occurs
        return reader;
    }
    private LineMapper<User> getLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<User> lineMapper=new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"Roll Number","Name of Student","Personal Email ID","Email ID","MOBILE NO"});
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper=new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return lineMapper;
    }
    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor(){
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer(){
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer= new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<User>());
        writer.setSql("insert into user(rollNo,name,personalEmail,officialEmail,mobileNo) values (:rollNo,:name,:personalEmail,:officalEmail,:mobileNo)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Job importUserJob(){

        return new JobBuilder("USER_IMPORT_JOB")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(step1())
        .end()
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(){
        return new StepBuilder("Step 1")
        .<User,User>chunk(5)
        .reader(reader())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
    }
}
```

On building the project I am getting the following exceptions-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.spring_boot_batch_demo.SpringBootBatchDemoApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]     
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]  
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at com.example.spring_boot_batch_demo.SpringBootBatchDemoApplication.main(SpringBootBatchDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:371) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.399) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        ... 24 common frames omittedCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.boot.sql.init.DatabaseInitializationMode.ALWAYS
        at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.DatabaseInitializationMode.valueOf(DatabaseInitializationMode.java:26) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.OnDatabaseInitializationCondition.getDatabaseInitializationMode(OnDatabaseInitializationCondition.java:75) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.OnDatabaseInitializationCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnDatabaseInitializationCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

For referred several other posts which stated versioning problem, but it didn't help.
I cannot find the problem with the code, can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you please share application.properties file

Comment: I have added it now. Please check

Comment: If possible can you please share your code in some repo for debugging?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, please read my answer to know the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have analysed your code, Here are my findings.

1. Found some issues in `BatchConfig` class. You are using `new JobBuilder()`, `new StepBuilder()` while creating Job and Step. The right way is to use `JobBuilderFactory`, `StepBuilderFactory`.
2. I can see entity class (user) name is in lower, It should be in camelcase (User).

*PS: I tested with PostgreSQL database using these properties but I am sure it will work with MySQL database as well*

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/batch_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
#show the queries in the console
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#to format the queries for readability
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
server.port=8081
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
#spring.batch.job.enabled=false
#to initalize the tables
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ayushsingh</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_boot_batch_demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring_boot_batch_demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**BatchConfig**

```
package com.ayushsingh.spring_boot_batch_demo.config;

import com.ayushsingh.spring_boot_batch_demo.entities.User;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration //this is important- enables batch processing in the project
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> reader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<User> reader=new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("records.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper()); //how to map the line which is read.
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1); // skip lines when error occurs
        return reader;
    }
    private LineMapper<User> getLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<User> lineMapper=new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"Roll Number","Name of Student","Personal Email ID","SMVDU Email ID","MOBILE NO"});
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper=new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return lineMapper;
    }
    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor(){
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer(){
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer= new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<User>());
        writer.setSql("insert into user(rollNo,name,personalEmail,officialEmail,mobileNo) values (:rollNo,:name,:personalEmail,:officalEmail,:mobileNo)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }



    @Bean 
    public Job importUserJob(){

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("USER_IMPORT_JOB")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(step1())
        .end()
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step 1")
        .<User,User>chunk(5)
        .reader(reader())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for pointing out the mistakes. I made the necessary changes and ran the application. I think it worked but now am getting following errors-  org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[class path resource [records.csv]], input=[╩L1Xk?7ä┴xºC╗≤╖┴1∩òJ‼┤él!B|◄]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]
        at

Comment: Yes, this is valid error. Make sure file that you are trying to read is present at correct location

Comment: I hope your issue resolved now?

Comment: I checked the location but getting the same error. My excel file has following fields- (Excel Sheet Column No. : Column Name)- (A:S.No., B:Roll No., C:Name of the Student: D: Personal Email ID, E: Email ID , F: MOBILE NO). Also, the resources.csv is placed in the resources folder.

Comment: Please check this, I am facing this problem

Comment: Ok as this is different error so I suggest you to ask this in another question so that it help others as well.